Extract rows of data with partial match in a column from one sheet then populates 2nd sheet with matching row data
I have been trying to get this to work for a good part of a week, but am limited in my knowledge of VBA syntax so nothing I've been able to find has worked.  Please help.
I have 4 workbooks.  "Template", "Process", "CR" and "DQM" each having one sheet named the same as the workbook (except the Template one).  The "Template" workbook is my destination workbook with the other 3 being source workbooks with variable row and column data.  I have code in "Template" that loops through the data in "Process" and creates a "NewSheet" in "Template" for each value in "IDColumn" in "Process" and names the sheet with that value and populates some data on the "New Sheet".  Works beautiful.
Within the loop "i" that creates the sheets, I need to extract only rows from the "CR" workbook, where the "SORID" column contains (partial text) that matches the value for the "NewSheet" in the "Template" workbook.  The value I need to match on also gets populated on each "NewSheet" in cell "B4".  All matching rows in the "CR" source workbook should then get populated on rows on the matching "NewSheet" starting in cell "E5".  I do not want it to copy/paste, just populate the data.  (Note:  I have populated other data with out copy/paste by using code similar to:  WB1.WS1.Range.Value = WB2.WS2.RAnge.Value so I know it can be done and it is very fast.)
Once that is done, I need to do the same thing with the "DQM" workbook data as I did with the "CR" data, but it should populate 5 rows down from the last row of "CR" data, still starting in Column E.  I will also need to create a header for the DQM data that is 3 rows done from the last row of the CR data and will populate column headers on row beneath DQM Header.  One difference is i don't need to populate columns A and B in the destination worksheets, so extracting only part of each matching row.
CR Source Data
enter image description here
DQM Source Data
enter image description here
Template Final Result
Sheet 123456:  enter image description here
Sheet 234567: enter image description here
Sheet 345678: enter image description here
I have spreadsheets I can attach if someone can direct me how to do it.
I have tried variations using "InStr" and ".value=.value" type of code.  I have found bits and pieces of how to accomplish this, but am not experienced enough to tweak it to make it work for me and most were using a copy/paste scenario which I definitely do not want.
Please add comments to lines of code so I know what it is doing so I can learn.  Thank you very much for any assistance!
CR Data:



CR#
SORID
Title
Type
Current
Proposed
Submitted
Submission ID
Status
Notes




123
123456
Sample
Metadata
Yes
No
6/4/24
E734
Jira
Notes


124
123456, 678912
Sample
Model
No
Yes
6/4/24
E736
Jira
Notes


256
123456
Sample
Owner
Really long text
Really long text too
6/4/24
E736
Jira
Notes


6789
234567
Sample
Metadata
Yes
No
6/4/24
RTIM695
Jira
Notes


9214
123456, 234567, 456789
Sample
Model
Yes
No
6/4/24
123_CCCC
RSM
Notes



DQM Data:



iGrafx ID
Process Name
Date
Open
Name
Type
Element




345678
Name for 345678
4/1/24
70
Sample Text
Completeness
Owner


123456
Sample Name
2/6/22
425
Sample Text
Completeness
Applications


123456
Sample Name
6/1/24
10
Another sample
Accuracy
Work Products


345678
Name for 345678
3/9/23
360
Sample Text
Completeness
Applications


345678
Name for 345678
4/10/24
60
Another sample
Accuracy
Work Products



Template Destination File:



Data on
sheet "123456"

































Current Data


CR Header











iGrafx ID
123456


CR#
SORID
Title
Type
**Current  **
Proposed
Submitted
Submission ID
Status
Notes


Owner
Mary Smith


123
123456
Sample
Metadata
Yes
No
6/4/24
E734
Jira
Notes


Summary
Sample data for illistrative purposes.


124
123456, 678912
Sample
Model
No
Yes
6/4/24
E736
Jira
Notes






256
123456
Sample
Owner
Really long text
Really long text too
6/4/24
E736
Jira
Notes






































DQM Header















Date
Open
Name
Type
Element











2/6/22
425
Sample Text
Completeness
Applications











6/1/24
10
Another sample
Accuracy
Work Products








Code:
Sub Fill_Data_ProcessAttestation()


Everything from here to line 35 works fabulously

Dim AlignedProcesses As Worksheet  
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet  
Dim AttestTemplate As Workbook  
Dim lastRow As Long  
Dim i As Long  
Dim IDColumn  

Set AttestTemplate = ActiveWorkbook 'Template xlsm workbook/file

Set AlignedProcesses = Workbooks("Aligned Processes_data.csv").Sheets("Aligned Processes_Data")

IDColumn = 1 'Column to get the unique iGrafx IDs to create tabs

lastRow = AlignedProcesses.Cells(AlignedProcesses.Rows.Count, IDColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
With AttestTemplate
    Set NewSheet = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets("RAU Information"))
End With

TabName = AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, IDColumn)
NewSheet.Name = TabName

NewSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Details, DQM and Changes"
With NewSheet.Range("A1:N1")
    .MergeCells = True
End With

NewSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "Current Details"
NewSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = "Proposed Changes"

NewSheet.Range("A4:A29").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Workbooks("Aligned Processes_data.csv").Sheets("Aligned Processes_data").Range("A1:Z1").Value)
NewSheet.Range("B4:B29").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Workbooks("Aligned Processes_data.csv").Sheets("Aligned Processes_data").Range(AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, IDColumn), AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, IDColumn + 25)).Value)


Here's the code that I"m having issues with.  From here to the end of the "d" loop.  I have commented where things are working properly.

    Dim OpenCRs As Worksheet  
    Dim CRSourcelastRow As Long  
    Dim CRDestLastRow As Long  
    Dim SORIDColumn  
    Dim CRIDColumn  
    Dim c As Long  
    
    SORIDColumn = 3
    CRIDColun = 1
    
    'These next 2 lines work fine-no issue
    Set OpenCRs = Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR")
    NewSheet.Cells(3, 5).Value = "Open Change Requests"
    
    CRSourcelastRow = OpenCRs.Cells(OpenCRs.Rows.Count, SORIDColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row on CR csv source file
    CRDestLastRow = NewSheet.Cells(NewSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row of CR data on relative sheet in destination file "Template"
    
    NewSheet.Range("E4:N4").Value = Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR").Range("A1:J1").Value  'Works fine
    
    On Error Resume Next


This "For" loop should find all rows in the source CSV file where the SORIDColumn contains the value that is the tab/sheet name created in the "i" loop.  Then It should write those rows to the "Template" file starting in column E, row 5.

    For c = 2 To CRSourcelastRow
        If InStr(Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR").Cells(c, SORIDColumn).Value, TabName) Then
            NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 1, 5).End(xlToRight).Value = OpenCRs.Range(c, CRIDColumn).End(xlToRight).Value
        End If
    Next c

    
    Dim DQM As Worksheet
    Dim d As Long
    Dim DQMSourceLastRow As Long
    Dim DQMDestLastRow As Long
    Dim iGrafxIDColumn
    iGrafxIDColumn = 1
    
    Set DQM = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM")
    NewSheet.Cells(CRTblLastRow + 3, 5).Value = "DQM Anomalies" 'Works fine
    
    DQMSourceLastRow = DQM.Cells(DQM.Rows.Count, iGrafxIDColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row on DQM csv source file
    DQMDestLastRow = NewSheet.Cells(NewSheet.Rows.Count, CRDestLastRow + 5).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row of DQM data on relative sheet in destination file "Template"
    
    NewSheet.Range(CRDestLastRow + 4, 5).End(xlToRight).Value = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM").Range("C1:I1").Value
    
    On Error Resume Next


This "For" loop should find all rows in the source CSV file where the iGrafxIDColumn contains the value that is the tab/sheet name created in the "i" loop.  Then It should write those rows to the "Template" file starting in column E, 5 rows below the last row in the CR data range (loop "c").

    For d = 2 To DQMSourceLastRow
        If InStr(Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM").Cells(d, iGrafxIDColumn).Value, TabName) Then
            NewSheet.Range(DQMDestLastRow + 1, 5).End(xlToRight).Value = DQM.Range(d, iGrafxIDColumn).End(xlToRight).Value
        End If
    Next d

Next i

End Sub


Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.
Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

If you have working code which you need to modify, it's best to edit your question and include that code - at least that gives anyone interested in helping out a starting point.

@taller  Sorry.  I didn't know how to do it properly.

@Tim Williams I have uploaded sample source tables and destination tables for how the final result should be laid out.  I am unable to log into this forum from work and can't send outside the org, so will have to duplicate the code tomorrow manually.  My biggest issue is finding partial text in the source file that matches the destination file sheet name which is a number.  Finding all rows that match, then populating them on the destination file in the correct place.

Wating for your code.

If SORID contains one or more comma-separated values then you can check for a single value match by using Split(cellContentHere,",") to give you an array of separate values - loop over that array and test each element against your search string.

FYI your company is hobbling you if they don't allow access to something like SO...   Code is rarely confidential.

@TimWilliams I don't do this very often.  The folks in tech probably aren't restricted like me.

I have added the code with comments.

After copying a row from (eg) the CR sheet you need to increment the destination row CRDestLastRow = CRDestLastRow +1   Otherwise you just copy all records to the same row.

Also add Option Explicit at the top of your module to catch typos like CRIDColun = 1

CRTblLastRow is not defined?

Untested but this should be close:
Option Explicit

Sub Fill_Data_ProcessAttestation()
    'use constants for fixed values
    Const ID_COL_PROC As Long = 1
    Const ID_COL_SOR As Long = 3
    Const ID_COL_CR As Long = 2
    Const ID_COL_GRAFX As Long = 1
    
    Dim AlignedProcesses As Worksheet, wsAPD As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet, OpenCRs As Worksheet, TabName
    Dim AttestTemplate As Workbook, DQM As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, lastePasteRow As Long
    
    Set AttestTemplate = ActiveWorkbook 'Template xlsm workbook/file  ? ThisWorkbook ?
    
    Set AlignedProcesses = Workbooks("Aligned Processes_data.csv").Sheets("Aligned Processes_Data")
    lastrow = LastValueRow(AlignedProcesses, ID_COL_PROC)
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    
        TabName = AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, ID_COL_PROC)
        Set NewSheet = AttestTemplate.Worksheets.Add( _
                   After:=AttestTemplate.Worksheets("RAU Information"))
        With NewSheet
            .Name = TabName
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Details, DQM and Changes"
            .Range("A1:N1").MergeCells = True
            .Cells(3, 2).Value = "Current Details"
            .Cells(3, 3).Value = "Proposed Changes"
            .Cells(3, 5).Value = "Open Change Requests"
            CopyValues AlignedProcesses.Range("A1:Z1"), .Range("A4"), True 'True = transpose
            CopyValues AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 26), _
                                                        .Range("B4"), True
        End With
        
        Set OpenCRs = Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR")
        Set DQM = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM")
        
        'copy CR data and return the row number of the last-pasted row
        lastePasteRow = CopyMatchedRows(OpenCRs.Range("A1:J1"), _
                                        ID_COL_SOR, TabName, _
                                        NewSheet.Range("E4"), _
                                        "No Open CRs")
        
        NewSheet.Cells(lastePasteRow + 3, "E").Value = "DQM Anomalies"
        
        'copy DQM data and return the row number of the last-pasted row
        lastePasteRow = CopyMatchedRows(DQM.Range("C1:I1"), _
                                        ID_COL_GRAFX, TabName, _
                                        NewSheet.Cells(lastePasteRow + 5, "E"), _
                                        "No Open DQM Anomalies")
        
        Debug.Print "Last-pasted row: ", lastePasteRow
        
    Next i

End Sub

'Copy matched rows, starting with the headers(always copied)
'  Data rows are copied if the value in the column `idColNum` of that row
'  contains a match for `idValue`
'   rw:         the first row(headers) of the source table
'   idColNum:   column number of the id value(s) in each data row
'   idValue:    the id to be tested against
'   cDest:      the first paste position (single cell)
'   NoDataMsg:  message placed under the first header if no data rows were copied
Function CopyMatchedRows(rw As Range, idColNum As Long, idValue, cDest As Range, _
                                                Optional NoDataMsg As String = "") As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, v, arr, i As Long, copiedData As Boolean
    
    lastrow = LastValueRow(rw.Worksheet, rw.Cells(idColNum).Column) 'last-used row in ID column
    
    CopyValues rw, cDest        'copy the headers
    Set rw = rw.Offset(1)       'first row of data
    copiedData = False          'default
    Do While rw.Row <= lastrow
        v = rw.EntireRow.Cells(idColNum).Value        'id value
        arr = Split(v, ",")                 'get an array of id values
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)  'loop id column values
            If Trim(arr(i)) = Trim(idValue) Then  'id match?
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1) 'next paste position
                CopyValues rw, cDest        'copy the data row
                CopyMatchedRows = cDest.Row 'last paste destination
                copiedData = True           'matched at least one row
                Exit For                    'stop looping
            End If
        Next i
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1) 'next data row
    Loop
    'if no rows were copied and a message was provided, add the message
    If Not copiedData And Len(NoDataMsg) > 0 Then
        cDest.Offset(1).Value = NoDataMsg
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1)
    End If
    
    CopyMatchedRows = cDest.Row 'last row filled
End Function


'Return the row of the last-populated cell in column `col` (numeric or letter) on sheet `ws`
Function LastValueRow(ws As Worksheet, col As Variant) As Long
    If Not IsNumeric(col) Then col = ws.Columns(col).Column 'user passed in column letter?
    LastValueRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

'copy values from rngSrc to rngDest, optionally transposed
Function CopyValues(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, Optional Transposed As Boolean = False)
    Dim arr
    If rngSrc.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        rngDest(1).Value = rngSrc.Value
    Else
        arr = IIf(Transposed, Application.Transpose(rngSrc.Value), rngSrc.Value)
        rngDest(1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
    End If
End Function


WOW!  That's amazing.  Super fast.  Thank you so much!  One last question.  How would I have it populate the first data row of the CR and DQM sections with "No Open CRs" and "No Open DQM Anomalies", respectively, when no matching rows are found?

I just noticed an issue.   This line only populates the data in cell  B4 and doesn't bring over the rest of the data now.        CopyValues AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, ID_COL_PROC), .Range("B4"), True

I tried:  CopyValues AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, ID_COL_PROC+25), .Range("B4"), True        and  I tried:  CopyValues AlignedProcesses.Cells(i, ID_COL_PROC), .Range("B4:B29"), True                        but neither fixed it.

I forgot to add .Resize(1,26) to the source range for that call.  See edited code above.

...added edits to CopyMatchedRows to allow for providing a "no rows found" message

Thank you!  We got it now.  I ended up having the cell in the first row after the header display the "No Data" message instead of a popup.   I don't have enough reputation points so I can't vote on your solution. Thank you for all your help!  I learned a lot.

Good to hear it's working out.

There is a problem with the assigning values in this part of code:
 For c = 2 To CRSourcelastRow
        If InStr(Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR").Cells(c, SORIDColumn).Value, TabName) Then
            NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 1, 5).End(xlToRight).Value = OpenCRs.Range(c, CRIDColumn).End(xlToRight).Value
        End If
    Next c

Either use Copy and PasteSpecial
 For c = 2 To CRSourcelastRow
        If InStr(Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR").Cells(c, SORIDColumn).Value, TabName) Then
            OpenCRs.Range(OpenCRs.Cells(c, CRIDColumn),OpenCRs.Cells(c, CRIDColumn+9)).Copy
            NewSheet.Range(NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 1, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
        CRDestLastRow = CRDestLastRow + 1
    Next c

or with the exact Range.Value assignment:
For c = 2 To CRSourcelastRow
        If InStr(Workbooks("CR.csv").Sheets("CR").Cells(c, SORIDColumn).Value, TabName) Then
            NewSheet.Range(NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 1, 5),NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 1, 14)).Value = OpenCRs.Range(OpenCRs.Cells(c, CRIDColumn),OpenCRs.Cells(c, CRIDColumn+9)).Value
        End If
        CRDestLastRow = CRDestLastRow + 1
crt    Next c

And problems here:
Set DQM = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM")
    NewSheet.Cells(CRTblLastRow + 3, 5).Value = "DQM Anomalies" 'Works fine  This variable is not defined!!!
    
    DQMSourceLastRow = DQM.Cells(DQM.Rows.Count, iGrafxIDColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row on DQM csv source file
    DQMDestLastRow = NewSheet.Cells(NewSheet.Rows.Count, CRDestLastRow + 5).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row of DQM data on relative sheet in destination file "Template"
    
    NewSheet.Range(CRDestLastRow + 4, 5).End(xlToRight).Value = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM").Range("C1:I1").Value


Change for this
Set DQM = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM")
    NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 3, 5).Value = "DQM Anomalies" 
    
    DQMSourceLastRow = DQM.Cells(DQM.Rows.Count, iGrafxIDColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row on DQM csv source file
    DQMDestLastRow = NewSheet.Cells(NewSheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row 'correct the column value 'Find last row of DQM data on relative sheet in destination file "Template"
    
    NewSheet.Range(NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 4, 5), NewSheet.Cells(CRDestLastRow + 4, 11)).Value = Workbooks("DQM.csv").Sheets("DQM").Range("C1:I1").Value   'edited


Furtherly apply the same changes for the d loop as for the c loop.
Worth after to check the offsets of the different tables.
